# Split up shapefile into little shapefiles

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector

I have a very large shapefile (all the roads in RI). I need to split it up into chunks so that I can process the file with multiple worker threads in Python. So far I have created a grid in QGIS that is overlaid on the vector data. I then ran the intersection algorithm with the grid and the shapefile so that the vectors are split up and are assigned an `'id'` for the box they're part of.

Now, since all the vectors in a particular box of the grid all have the same `'id'`, can I extract them and save them to their own shapefile automatically? I am aware of selecting all vectors with an `'id'` and then copying them to their own layer and then saving that layer, but I have so many boxes/id's that it would take forever to save each of them off. How can I use QGIS to automatically make a new shapefile for each id/box?

Basically I want create a new shapefile for each distinct value of a particular field in the shapefile attributes.

Original Shapefile

[image]

Shapefile after grid intersection

[image]

A set of vectors which share the same bbox/id

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can split shapefile into multiple shapefiles based on any distinct field value using `Vector > Data Management Tools > Split Vector Layer`.

Select a field for `Unique ID field` option and a folder. All shapefiles will be created in that folder.

[image]